# Compilation error using Rcpp with typedef

Tags: c++, r, eigen, rcpp, r-package

I'm writing some C++ components for my R package using RcppEigen and I'm having trouble using typedefs in this context. The following code won't compile:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

typedef Eigen::ArrayXd MapAr1;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
MapAr1 myFun(const MapAr1& x){

  MapAr1 y = x;
  y[0] = 0;

  return y;

}
```

Here is the error:

```
==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated src/RcppExports.cpp
* Updated R/RcppExports.R

==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Updating my_package documentation
Loading my_package
Re-compiling my_package
'/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
  --quiet CMD INSTALL '/my_path/my_package'  \
  --library='/tmp/RtmpgPjAdf/devtools_install_125071da0b53' --no-R --no-data  \
  --no-help --no-demo --no-inst --no-docs --no-exec --no-multiarch  \
  --no-test-load 

* installing *source* package ‘my_package’ ...
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/my_path/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I" /my_path/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RcppEigen/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
** libs
RcppExports.cpp:10:1: error: ‘MapAr1’ does not name a type
 MapAr1 myFun(const MapAr1& x);
 ^
RcppExports.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* my_package_myFun(SEXP)’:
RcppExports.cpp:15:42: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type [-fpermissive]
     Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MapAr1& >::type x(xSEXP);
                                          ^
RcppExports.cpp:15:50: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MapAr1& >::type x(xSEXP);
                                                  ^
RcppExports.cpp:15:58: error: expected initializer before ‘x’
     Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MapAr1& >::type x(xSEXP);
                                                          ^
RcppExports.cpp:16:40: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
     rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(myFun(x));
                                        ^
RcppExports.cpp:16:41: error: ‘myFun’ was not declared in this scope
     rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(myFun(x));
                                         ^
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘my_package’
* removing ‘/tmp/RtmpgPjAdf/devtools_install_125071da0b53/my_package’
Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

The same code compiles outside the package. So I'm guessing that something is not copied properly to the RcppExports files. I also noticed a similar problem when trying to use the RcppEigen namespace: `using namespace RcppEigen;` is not copied.

Any idea how to solve this without modifying RcppExports by hand? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are making your life too complicated by insisting on the `typedef`. Once you include it in the file, *and your function signature*, it becomes part of the interface and hence also needs to be in your `RcppExports.cpp`.  So you need to provide it 'one level higher'.

But there is a provision for that: call the file `pkgname_types.h` and it will be included.  I created a simple package `eigentest` and added a file `eigentest_types.h` in the `src/` directory:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>

typedef Eigen::ArrayXd MapAr1;
```

and then added it to your code snippet with

```
#include "eigentest_types.h"
```

instead of the `typedef`.

That's all you need -- just replace `eigentest` with your package name.